# Automatically enable a command inside R function to use its arguments (formals)

Tags: r

Below is example  data and a function (`barplot2`) that I have written. You will notice that `barplot2` only calculates co-ordinates and then uses `polygon` command. For now, I have only specified arguments for `lwd` and `col` in the function which can be passed on to the `polygon` command inside the function. But the `polygon` command is already capable of accepting several `arguments` such as `density`, `border`, `angle`, etc. Is there a proper way to write my function so that I don't have to individually enumerate all those `arguments` and still be able to use them.

```
set.seed(100)
Mydata = rnorm(65)
Year = 1950:2014

plot(Year, Mydata, type = 'p', pch = NA, xlab = "", ylab = "")

barplot2 <- function(x, y, lwd = 1, col = "grey"){
    w = ((max(x) - min(x))/length(x)) * 0.75
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
        x1  = x[i] - w/2
        x2 = x[i] + w/2
        y1 = 0
        y2 = y[i]
        polygon(x = c(x1,x2,x2,x1), y = c(y1,y1,y2,y2), lwd = lwd, col = col)
    }
}
barplot2(Year,Mydata)
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the `...` idiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `...` to be able to pass unassigned arguments to the functions

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure @manotheshark has the solution you're looking for, but I'll expand on it.

change the function to

```
barplot2 <- function(x, y, lwd = 1, col = "grey",...){
    w = ((max(x) - min(x))/length(x)) * 0.75
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
        x1  = x[i] - w/2
        x2 = x[i] + w/2
        y1 = 0
        y2 = y[i]
        polygon(x = c(x1,x2,x2,x1), y = c(y1,y1,y2,y2), lwd = lwd, col = col,...)
    }
}
```

And that should give you the result you want.

Edit:
Other options can be specified like this

```
Barplot2(Year,Mydata, angle=45,lty = 2)
```

Just keep going in that fashion and all the arguments will get passed into the polygon function.